# How to migrate/upgrade ExtJS 3.2 to ExtJS 4.2 download and How to download the migrated file?

Tags: download, extjs4.2, extjs3, migrate

I read regarding this -
--> use `extjs-all-debug.js` at time of development and migration. Compatibility mode require `ext-compat.js` and `ext-core-compat.js` files.

Comment: Can't able to download the file from sencha also. Can Someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Download: http://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/ext-4.2.1-gpl.zip

Sencha already release ExtJS 6. If possible, use this instead.

Comment: Thank you @Perryflynn. Can you give me ext-js 4. Instead of 4.2? I will be grateful to you. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look into the extjs api docs and change the version code in the download url. ;)